# Select from table iterating through subset first

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a query:

```
 select USERNAME, BIRTHDATE, USERID, LASTONLINE, LOCATIONNAME (etc) 
 from [User] 
 where AccountDisabled <> 1 (and a whole bunch of other criteria) 
 order by LastOnline desc offset
 @skip rows fetch next 40 rows only
```

Now, I've been given a list of [User].UserIds that take priority in this search - we want to iterate through these [User]s first, filtering out the users that match the search criteria, and return those as well as the next 40 from the overall [User] table that match.

How can this be done, with performance taken into consideration as a priority?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is probably `UNION ALL`:

```
select USERNAME, BIRTHDATE, USERID, LASTONLINE, LOCATIONNAME (etc) 
 from [User] 
 where AccountDisabled <> 1 (and a whole bunch of other criteria) 
AND USERID IN (list of userids)

UNION ALL

select * from 
 (

    select USERNAME, BIRTHDATE, USERID, LASTONLINE, LOCATIONNAME (etc) 
     from [User] 
     where AccountDisabled <> 1 (and a whole bunch of other criteria) 
    AND USERID NOT IN (list of userids)
     order by LastOnline desc offset
     @skip rows fetch next 40 rows only
 ) as dt
```

Or you apply some `ROW_NUMBER` logic like this:

```
select *
from
 (
    select USERNAME, BIRTHDATE, USERID, LASTONLINE, LOCATIONNAME (etc),
        CASE WHEN USERID IN (list of userids) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS grp
        ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER (PARTITION BY CASE WHEN USERID IN (list of userids) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
              ORDER BY LastOnline desc) AS rn
     from [User] 
     where AccountDisabled <> 1 (and a whole bunch of other criteria) 
 ) as dt
 where grp = 0
    or rn BETWEEN @skip AND @skip + 40
```

Comment: I'll have to play with these.  Any idea which way is best for performance?  I can always test it out of course.

Comment: Thank you so much by the way - this is awesome.

Comment: You should find the performance very similar as a RowNumber filter actually just uses a TOP to limit the rows

http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86415/retrieving-n-rows-per-group

Comment: @RobVious: Performance will mainly depend on the number of rows returned by the selectivity of *whole bunch of other criteria*, indexing might be hard. The `ROW_NUMBER` version might be cached in the middle layer to avoid re-calculatiing it for pagination.

Comment: Is the "select TOP 40" necessary there?

Comment: @RobVious: Of course not as there's also SKIP/FETCH, removed it.

Comment: Is there any way you can use Not Exists instead of Not In here for the ids?  I'm using this where `userids` is 10k items and it's taking a long time :(

Comment: @RobVious: 10k priority users? Where do you get this list from, can't you load them to a table? Then you can use `NOT EXISTS` (but the optimizer should choose the a similar, unless the columns are NULLable).

Comment: Actually - the goal is to load up the first 20 from the first set, and if there aren't 20 there, load up more from the second set.  But the list of Ids is fetched prior based on other business logic.  Are you available for paid consultation so I can have you take a look at my code?

Comment: @RobVious: Sorry, I only do Teradata consulting & training for years, my SQL Server knowledge is bit outdated :)